# Where should I put test support code for a Java library

Tags: unit-testing, maven, module

I have a Maven project which is used as a library in other projects. The setup is pretty standard: `src/main` with the library code, `src/test` with test cases for `src/main`.

Let's assume I have a project `foo` which depends in this library. `foo` also has test cases. To help writing tests in `foo` for code that uses my library, I'd like to give `foo` a support framework to write tests (like setting up a mock environment).

Where can I put this support code?

- It shouldn't go into `src/main` because it's not meant to go into production.
- It can't go into `src/test` because creating a dependency from `foo`'s tests to the tests of the library adds too much junk to the classpath (like `logback-test.xml` config files, tests which are never executed, ...).

I could put the code into a new module but it's tightly coupled with the code in `src/main`, so I'd like to keep it in the same project (would also allow the test support code to access package private fields and methods).

Also, the code in `src/test` should have access to it, so that I can use it to write my own unit tests.

What are my options with Maven to keep this in the same project but still separate it cleanly from both `src/main` and `src/test`? Can I somehow create a third output JAR for, say, `src/test-support`? Or should I put the code into `src/test` and then use filters in the JAR plugin to include only the support code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a POM fragment which splits the main JAR into the normal artifact and a "JUnit support JAR":

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <index>true</index>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/junit/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>junit-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <classifier>junit</classifier>
                        <archive>
                            <index>true</index>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/junit/**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>test-jar</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

In a nutshell, it looks for any package with `junit` in its name and puts it into the JUnit JAR, excluding it from the normal artifact.

If the coordinate for the normal jar is

```
<groupId>com.group</groupId>
<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
```

then you can get the JUnit support code by simply adding `<classifier>junit</classifier>`:

```
<groupId>com.group</groupId>
<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
<classifier>junit</classifier>
```

So to use this, the POM which depends on `com.group:foo` will look like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <classifier>junit</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Sometimes, you will need JUnit to compile your "JUnit support JAR". If that's the case, use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

to include JUnit into the build. This will make the dependency available at compile time but it will not leak to anyone else.

Comment: You could just bind the 2 separate jar plugin tasks to different phases. So, when you run mvn.bat test install then the test phase can make the first jar and the install phase can create the second one right?  Just an idea to add.

Comment: @djangofan: I guess I could do that but what would be the advantage?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the Maven Jar Plugin

[Maven Jar Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html)

Since you're using Maven you can just cut a separate artifact of the project that contains the libraries you want to use in foo add the following plugin to create another jar artifact:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <executions>
       <execution>
          <goals>
              <goal>test-jar</goal>
          </goals>
       </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

This creates a second jar in this project of everything in the src/test directory.

[Test Jars](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html)

You could splice out the stuff in that jar you don't need with some filters.

Then to use this library you would include this as a dependancy in foo:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>your.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-artifact-id</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

To separate the projects further you can also create a test only project with your more frameworky test jars.
See How to create a jar containing test classes (Preferred way) in the Maven Jar Plugin doc

Comment: Is it possible to create a normal tests jar (with all code from `src/test`) and another one with a filtered set of files?

Comment: Should be able to do that by running the plugin twice with different classifiers http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Doesn't work :-( The goal `test-jar` ignores the value in `classifier` and always uses `tests`. It works as expected with goal `jar` but then, it only looks for classes in `src/main`, so the JAR is always empty.

Comment: So looking further down the doc I sent you it appears that they recommend creating a separate project for the tests if you want to further separate it: The preferred way

In order to let Maven resolve all test-scoped transitive dependencies you should create a separate project.

Comment: Yes but then, I would have three projects in my work space :-/ I'd prefer to have less projects rather than more :-)

Comment: Why?  Generally your code would be more modular when it has more modules.

Comment: Daniel: As I explained in my question, the code doesn't compile when it's spread over modules.

Comment: @tieTYT: It would be more modular but I also would have 0% code coverage from tests...