# Maven test dependency in release phase

Tags: java, unit-testing, maven

We have a very strange problem, especially since the same solution works in other parts of the project.

We're working with Maven 3

We have a module with unit tests and some classes (i.e. mocks) in a module A.
Module B, depends on A for both sources and test sources.

So we've done the following:

In module A:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Then in module B's pom we put:

```
     <!--Source dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--Test dependency-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

So, when we build the project everything works, from what I know the build runs the "install" phase, so it makes sense everything works.
Now, we're trying to make a relase and during the compile phase of module B, we always get:

> Failed to execute goal on project B: Could not resolve dependencies
>   for project myGroup:B:war:1.5.0.0: Failure to find
>   myGroup:A:jar:tests:1.5.0.0 in "Link to our artifactory" was cached in
>   the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the
>   update interval of "company name" has elapsed or updates are forced

From what I can see in the build log it happens during the execution of the "maven-compiler-plugin", so why does it try to get the test jar which is a dependency in the test scope only?

This is not the 1st time we've used this method in our project and it has always worked (and we've released several releases thus far).

Comment: This looks like your multi-module build is not working correctly. I assume you have a missing dependency which means in other words the order of building is not what it should be. I would suggest to clean your local repository and try your build via `mvn clean package` i assume that will fail.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I deleted the entire repository and then run mvn clean and then maven package. Nothing fails

Comment: Are yoo sure you're using Maven 4? It doesn't appear to be publicly available, not even as a beta version.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo I'll fix it

Comment: Can you share your full POM's and the exact Maven commands you are running?  I am using Maven 3 on multiple multi-module projects with exactly the mentioned set up and have never faced a problem.

Comment: Hi, I don't think it would reflect much after I remove the company name, product names, etc. (and it's also a lot of work)

Comment: Does your release build include both module A and module B?  If it includes only module B, then the problem is that it can't find the test jar from module A in the repository.  You will need either to run mvn install on module A on the same machine, or mvn deploy on module A on some machine.  Note that mvn package on both module A and module B will resolve the dependency but will not install it in a local or remote repository.

Comment: It builds both modules

Comment: Have very much the same problem. And

Answer (score 0):

Some background: Maven uses two classpaths (compile and test) and therefore, you will see that the Maven compile plugin is invoked *twice* (once the production code and once for the tests).

The error above means that Maven can't find the dependency `myGroup:A:jar:tests:1.5.0.0` anywhere. If that happens in the first compile phase (production code), then that means test code leaked into the production ("compile") classpath which is bad.

If it happens while compiling tests, then it means that you have a typo somewhere.

What I can see from the code above: `<type>test-jar</type>` is wrong. `<type>` is always `jar`. To get what you want, you need to set the `classifier`:

```
<!--Test dependency-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>myGroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <classifier>tests</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

That said, here is a different solution to export mocks and test utilities: [Where should I put test support code for a Java library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991083/where-should-i-put-test-support-code-for-a-java-library/20149160#20149160)

Comment: Thank you, we'll try. But could you please elaborate why <type>test-jar</type> is wrong?

Comment: In addition, how could I test that I have no "leaks"?

Comment: There is no type `test-jar`; search for "The current core packaging values are" on http://maven.apache.org/pom.html for a list of valid values. 2. Testing for leaks: I know no automated way to do this.

Comment: Okay, thank you. We will try. I find the maven documentation very confusing and cyclic. It is very hard for us to understand it

Comment: Do you mean that I just need to change the dependency or also eliminate the plugin definition in module A?

Comment: Ah. Maybe you're confusing *goals* with *types*. There is a goal `test-jar` which means "build a JAR which contains the code for the test cases". The output is of type `jar` with the classifier `tests`. That way, Maven can tell the two apart. To fix your issue, just change the dependency and leave everything else as it is.

Comment: Note that this means module `B`'s tests will now see everything that si in `A`'s tests. That might be too much. If you have resources with the same name and path in both projects, you will have to change the whole build using the information from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991083/where-should-i-put-test-support-code-for-a-java-library/20149160#20149160

Comment: Aaron, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: There is type test-jar. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html

Answer (score 0):

We have a very same situation and our workaround was to add a 2nd "dumb" execution of the jar plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>dumb</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that on a straight forward multi-module project we found that this isn't required. `mvn compile` on moduleB doesn't require the test-jar of moduleA on a straight forward multi-module.

Comment: we found the problem. In our case, the moduleB was using maven-ant-run to do some resource filtering. But for some reason ant-run plugin required the test-jar, test dependency to be resolved. We therefore used resources plugin instead to do the resource filtering and ditched ant-run.