# How can I define a third Java source folder for Maven which gets compiled into a third JAR?

Tags: maven-3, maven-compiler-plugin

By default, Maven standard directory layout has two Java source folders:

```
src/main/java
src/test/java
```

For my purposes, I need a third one `src/junit/java` which should be packaged into a JAR with the classifier `junit`.

If possible, the new source folder should have it's own classpath (compile + everything with scope `junit`).

My guess is that for this, I will have to modify at least the resource and compile plugins.

Or is there an easier way?

I have a [workaround as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149160/34088) but for that, I have to put things like Mockito and JUnit on the `compile` classpath which violates my sense of purity.

For all people who doubt the wisdom of my approach: I have support code that help to write unit tests when you work with code from `src/main/java`. Since I'm using the same support code in the tests for the project itself, this code needs to be compiled *after* `src/main/java` and *before* `src/test/java`.

Specifically, my support code needs to import code from `src/main/java` and the tests need to be able to import the support code.

Comment: Why can't your support code be included in the test directory?  If the dependencies are right it will come ahead of the test code that needs it, right?

Comment: @DrLivingston: Because I have other projects which need the support code as well.

Comment: I guess I'm still missing something. Just with what you're saying it sounds like your support code needs it's own location, and then your test code should depend on it and the main code? (which is I think more or less what INK's answer below is suggesting)

Comment: My dependency tree is main <- support <- test but maven doesn't allow me to build something between main and test, hence my question. INK's suggestion works but I'd like something which only needs a single module instead of three (Eclipse can get really slow when you have many Maven modules open).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen a couple of Maven setups, which bundle test code in an own Maven module. You could then create a simple main-module <- support-module <- test-module dependency chain with that. But then main-module would compile fine, if you build it on it's own without test-module. Ofc you could aggreate them together with a reactor-pom and just build the project via this pom.

Edit:

If you have problems with this setup regarding code coverage, you can use the Jacoco Maven plugin to aggregate the test coverage generated by test-module to main-module. See this for further information: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

Comment: I know that this is possible but then, the test coverage for all three modules will be 0% in tools like Sonar.

Comment: Did you try using Jacoco for generating the code coverage data and then using the Sonar Jacoco plugin? I know that I did it that way a while ago and it worked. Sadly, I don't have any access to the poms anymore :( Maybe this can help you find a solution: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/creating-code-coverage-reports-for-unit-and-integration-tests-with-the-jacoco-maven-plugin/

Comment: I feel that blog post gets me a huge step closer to my goal. Please edit your answer and add this information.